# Regex: another case of "Matching all strings EXCEPT a specific series of strings

Tags: regex, regex-negation

This question is similar to many other questions about regex I found on this and other sites online. However the solutions did not work when trying to implement them. It is properly due to my own ignorance that it did not work but I would like to get help with the following:

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:**

I am working on importing data into our new database. Most of the conversion was done a few month ago and now I need to convert all new data.

**GENERAL INFORMATION ON ENVIRONMENT:**

To convert one specific field correctly I need to use regular expressions. The field in the new database can hold any of the following 3 values:

```
- Kid
- No Mail
- Household
```

However the column in the source file has a lot more values which I want to ignore.

The import program has a feature to create "Dictionaries" which can be applied to a specific field to translate the imported value to a standard value in the database. This is great to fix common typos etc.

The dictionary is very simple. You have a list of correct values and each correct value can have a number of incorrect values.

For example:

```
    CORRECT VALUE           IMPORT VALUES
    Kid                     kid
                            kids
                            Child
                            Minor
```

In the Import value list you can also enter regular expressions.

**PROBLEM TO SOLVE:**

Here is is a sample of the dictionary file:

```
     CORRECT VALUE LIST     IMPORT VALUE
  -  Kid                    Kid
                            KID

  -  No Mail                No Mail
                            NO MAIL

  -  Household              HH

  -  OTHER                Regex expression to match: Anything else
```

**EXAMPLES:**

Input Value:

- `KID`          converts to       `Kid`
- `HH`           converts to       `Household`
- `John`         converts to       `OTHER`
- `Do Not Call`  converts to       `OTHER`
- `NO MAIL`      converts to       `No Mail`
- `ABCD`         converts to       `OTHER`

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

This is what I have found online and adapted to my case:

Formula found on codinghorror.com:

`(?!kid|KID|Kid\b)\b\w+`          - This works for 'KID' but fails
                                          when I add anything 
                                          else for some reason

Formula found on stackoverflow.com:

`^(?!kid$).*`                     - Matches everything -even 'Kid'

`^((?!kid).)*$`                   - Same

This is the first time I have to use regex and I just need to have a little help to get started on it.

So any help or pointer you can give me is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `formula found on codinghorror.com` - now that's a distinction. )

Comment: Speaking seriously, I'm still unable to understand your question, perhaps because it's mostly about the solutions you've worked out, not the problem. Rephrasing it, clearly stating what's in the inputs of the program, and what should be the output, might be helpful not only for me. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Thank you. I have added some examples. I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend looking for a different solution to your importing job as this is going to get unwieldy very fast. However, if you really want to here's how to build a regex that will at least do what you ask (if I've understood you correctly, and if your regex engine supports this form as you didn't mention which one you're using).

```
(?!^(kid|KID|Kid|no mail)$).*
```

What that does is that ^ matches the beginning of the string and $ the end of the string(or sometimes the beginning and ending of lines, but if these are all one line values then that doesn't matter). You can wrap anything in (?!) to mean "don't match if this matches" and .* matches anything at all. Putting | between 2 patterns matches either of those patterns. So if any of the strings in the middle separated by the | match and there's nothing before or after (that's what the ^ and $ mean) then the bit inside the (?!) matches, and if that matches then the thing as a whole *doesn't* match. If the first bit is ok then the .* will match anything so the thing as a whole *will* match.

So that's how you do it, but do consider rethinking the problem as there's almost certainly a better solution to what you're trying to do. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest my head starts to smoke at this a little bit. (I'm confident I'll master it soon!).  I tried your solution and when I input `'Kid'` it returns `'k'`. Anything else matches and returns a blank. .. I am not sure about the engine I am using. The Database program I am using is called "Raiser's Edge" by Blackbaud. The import program I am using is called "Import-O-Matic" and is a plugin for "Raiser's Edge". Import-O-Matic was written in VB.Net I believe. Please excuse my ignorance but I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The caret (`^`) needs to go outside the lookahead, like the OP has it.  The way you have it, the regex will match at every position that isn't the beginning of the string, just because it isn't the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Thank you for your answers. I feel I have to clarify that the input is  only max 12 characters long (and comes from a csv table). The ENTIRE input value cannot be: `kid|Kid|no Mail|HH`  etc. We do not have to search within the input string.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  With the caret outside the lookahead, the regex tries to match at the beginning, and if it fails it fails.  If it's *inside* the lookahead, the regex will go on trying to match at subsequent positions.  It's the **whole regex** that needs to be anchored, not just the lookahead.

Comment: Ok. I made it work somehow:  `^(?!(Kid|Household|No Mail)$).*`  . I am not sure why this works but this has the desired effect in my environment. If it makes sense to anybody else please let me know. It might be that my software is too specialized or customized.

Answer (score 0):

To make the long story short, you have a list of possible output values, and, for each such a value, a finite set of possible values 'matching' it in the input. It looks like these `matches` are case-insensitive, but that might not actually be the case for all of them.

Now, the task is simple: for each input string, try to match it against this set. If it does match a particular pattern, find out which output value it belongs to - and place it in the result set. If not, use the blank value you have set (empty string, as I understand).

Going from theory to practice, that's how this approach can be implemented in JavaScript:

```
// defining the dictionary: each key is a possible output value,
// each element is a list of matching words
var dictionary = {
    Kid:       ['kid', 'kids', 'child', 'minor'],
    'No Mail': ['no mail'],
    HouseHold: ['HH']
};
var defaultOutput = ''; // self-explanatory

// preparing the dictionary of patterns
var outputs = Object.keys(dictionary), 
    patternsToMatch = {};

outputs.forEach(function(outValue) {
    var alternationPart = dictionary[outValue].join('|');
    patternsToMatch[outValue] = new RegExp(
        '^(?:' + alternationPart + ')$', 'i');
});

// actually processing the inputs:
var testInputs = ['KiD', 'kidi', 'cHiLd', 'no mail', 'no email'];
console.log(testInputs);

var results = testInputs.map(function(inputStr) {
    var matchingOutput = defaultOutput;
    outputs.some(function(outputVal) {
        if (patternsToMatch[outputVal].test(inputStr)) {
            matchingOutput = outputVal;
        }
        return matchingOutput !== defaultOutput;
    });
    return matchingOutput;
});
console.log(results);
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsuHD/).

It's simple (and has some corners cut, the aforementioned case-sensitivity issue among them), but (hopefully) shows the direction to think about.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your description above is quite correct, concise and simple. For now I made the regex somehow work. However I will refer to your java script example if I need something similar in the future.